# Where does the github actions output go?

Tags: c, github, makefile, output, github-actions

The github actions **should** build me an output because I ran the command make to make a file. However, I don't know where the output went now. Where is it or how can I get the file?
Thanks.

Comment: Read about artifacts in Actions docs

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references that might help you understand better about Github Actions and outputs:

- [Storing workflow data as artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts)
- [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs)
- [Workflow commands for Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions)
- [Actions Checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout)

Basically, when you use the `actions/checkout` action, you can execute commands from files from your Github repository.

In your case, the final location of the outputs will depend on what your command / script does in your Makefile.

You could eventually commit and push everything (using shell commands) at the end of the workflow execution for the file to appear on a specific branch of your git repository.